# What is the correct way to deserialize?

Tags: json, vb.net, linq

hello im saving a php array in .txt file using `json_encode`, next i need use this array in vb.net, but really i can do a while or for each,
this is the array string

```
"[{"Id_Event":"5713616","Deporte":"Soccer","Pais":"Austria Amateur","Liga":"Regionalliga East","Jornada":"20","Local":"SKU Amstetten","Visita":"Wiener SC Axa","Fecha_Evento":"2015-03-18T19:30:00","encuentros":[{"Items":[{"Por":"1","Fila":"3way15713616","Cuota":"1.9","$$hashKey":"019"}],"Tipo":"3way","Gan_Max":1.9,"$$hashKey":"017"}],"$$hashKey":"015"},{"Id_Event":"6804834","Deporte":"Soccer","Pais":"England Amateur","Liga":"Southern Football League,","Jornada":"1","Local":"Cambridge City","Visita":"Frome Town","Fecha_Evento":"2015-03-18T20:45:00","encuentros":[{"Items":[{"Por":"1","Fila":"3way16804834","Cuota":"1.7","$$hashKey":"01F"}],"Tipo":"3way","Gan_Max":1.7,"$$hashKey":"01D"}],"$$hashKey":"01B"}]"
```

in the project i have the `Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deserialize your json to a `List(Of JObject)` for the simplest way to be able to iterate through the json array :

```
Dim jsonString As String = "your_json_text"
Dim json As List(Of JObject) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of JObject))(jsonString)
For Each jObject As JObject In json
    Console.WriteLine(jObject)
Next
```

Better way would involve creating a class to map each item in your json array, then deserialize your json to `List(Of YourClass)` instead of `List(Of JObject)`.